# Find $f$ such that $f'(x) = x^3$ and the line $x + y = 0$ is tangent to $f$

Tags: calculus

> Find a function $f$ such that $f'(x) = x^3$ and the line $x + y = 0$ is tangent to the graph of $f$.

**Attempt:**

$f'(x) = x^3 \Rightarrow f(x) = x^4/4 + C$. My difficulty is in finding $C$ to meet the restriction that the line $y = -x$ is tangent to $f$. Using a graphic calculator I can *see* that $C \approx 0.8$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By integrating, we obtain $f(x) = \frac{x^{4}}{4} + C$. We wish to find the points on $f$ where the tangent line has slope $-1$, and use the constraint that $x + y = 0$. We have:

$f'(x) = -1$

$x^{3} = -1$

$x = -1$

Then, $f(-1)-1 = 0$, or:

$\frac{1}{4} + C - 1 = 0$

$C = \frac{3}{4}$

Thus, $\boxed{f(x) = \frac{x^{4} + 3}{4}}$

Answer (score 2):

The slope of the tangent line $y=-x$ is $-1$, so $f'(x)=x^3=-1$, so $x=-1$,

so, when $x=-1$, $y=-x=1=\dfrac{x^4}4+C=\dfrac14+C$.  Can you find $C$ from here?